# Video Orientation is Incorrect with any Apple mobile device (iPod, iPhone, iPad) for a Application using SkypeKit

Tags: c++, qt, qml, skype, video-conferencing

I'm developing an application in Qt(4.8.4) and using (the latest) SkypeKit version 4.5 for Desktop along with their C++ wrapper.

I've noticed that when I am in a video call with any Apple mobile device (iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch) the video orientation can be sideways or upsidedown.

**Is there anyway to check for and rotate incoming video calls so that they are orientated correctly?**

Otherwise, might this be a bug with skypekit?

To reproduce this, try running the qt_videocalls example that is shipped with SkypeKit 4.5. Login to a skype account and have someone call you from an apple device, the orientation will be incorrect on the desktop application when you rotate the apple device.